# AppendChild Link with onClick function

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm trying to use appendChild within Javascript to create a link that has a onClick attribute. I can't seem to make it work or find how to do this simple task.

```
var link=document.createElement("a");
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Link"));
link.href = '#';
link.onclick = 'loadScript()';
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: jQuery *could* make this a lot simpler (`$('<a href="#">Link</a>').click(loadScript).appendTo('body');`), but of course it comes with the library overhead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to change

```
link.onclick = 'loadScript()';
```

by

```
link.onclick = loadScript;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YZfJ2/)**

Comment: Better yet, `link.addEventListener('click', loadScript, false)`

Comment: How do I set it if loadscript has a parameter? `link.onclick = loadScript(it_is_here);` does not work for me.

Comment: @MsKhadijah : you could do `link.onclick = function() { loadScript(it_is_here); }`

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work. I cheated and used a switch statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var files = document.getElementById('files');
  document.getElementById('addLink').onclick = function () {
    var file = document.createElement('input');
    file.type = 'file';
    files.appendChild(file);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the function from running when declaring the call, the following worked for me:

```
link.onclick = function(){
    return loadScript()
}
```

Without problems you can send the variables you need to loadScript function.